# Control outputted decimal places globally

Tags: r, decimal, global

Is there a way to globally control the number of decimal places that show up in the print output in R? By globally, I mean something I can run at the beginning of an R session which applies to everything in that session. The default for me appears to be 6 decimals but I don't need that level of detail. I would like to accomplish this using base R, without using round() or any other formatting function at the prompt.

For example, assume I would like everything to print to 4 decimal places. Therefore I want 123.123 to appear as 123.1230, 123.123123 as 123.1231, and 123 as 123.0000, etc. Digits() won't accomplish this as it limits the entire output to the number of digits I specify.

Comment: There is no digits() or Digits() function in the base packages.

Comment: `options(digits=4)` or `options("digits"=4)` will display values rounded to four decimal places globally (the default is 7) after you set it. You can check the current value with `options("digits")`. However, numbers that can be displayed at their exact value with fewer decimal places won't be padded with extra zeros when you display them. To get a specific number of decimal places displayed you can use `format` or `sprintf`.

Comment: Thanks! That'll get me where I need to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it globally

```
getOption("digits")
[1] 6

x <- 10.30429032

options("digits" = 4)

x
[1] 10.3

options("digits" = 6)

x
[1] 10.3043
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what OP asked for, say I have x = 10.30429032 and y = 1000.30429032, setting the digits option to 6 would give x = 10.3043 and y = 1000.3, differing decimal places.